# How to create a job with postStart and preStop handlers by python kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

In the `create_namespaced_job` method there is no parameter that exists to define `preStop` and `postStart` handlers.

```
V1Job create_namespaced_job(namespace, body, pretty=pretty, dry_run=dry_run, field_manager=field_manager)
```

[Source](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#create_namespaced_job).

So, how to add these life-cycle handlers to a job or pod by Python Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

> In the create_namespaced_job method there is no parameter that exists to define preStop and postStart handlers.

The `preStop` and `postStart` handlers exists on the containers. You linked to the documentation for [create_namespaced_job](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#create_namespaced_job) and the parameter `body` is a [V1Job](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Job.md), and the `spec` of that has a `template`, that has a `spec` of type [V1PodSpec](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodSpec.md) and there you find a field `container[list]`and there you find a field `lifecycle` of type [V1Lifecylce](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Lifecycle.md) that has the `preStop` and `postStart`-handlers.

The documentation can also be navigated with `kubectl explain`, e.g:

```
kubectl explain podTemplate.template.spec.containers.lifecycle
```